# How to compute the metric Response for a Method with NDepend

Tags: ndepend

Is there any way to get the number of "source code lines" that could result from calling nested function?

For this question my example:

Selection of functions

| Function name | Lines of Code (LOC) [function body] |
| --- | --- |
| Function1 | 10 |
| Function2 | 20 |
| Function3 | 20 |

**Example 1**
Function1 
...|-> calls Function2
......|-> calls Function3
Sum of LOC= 50

**Example 2**
Function1
...|-> calls Function3
......|-> calls Function2
Sum of LOC= 50

**Example 3**
Function1
..|-> calls Function2
..|-> calls Function3
..|-> calls Function2
Sum of LOC= 70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code query that computes the **Response for each method of a code base**:

```
from m  in Application.Methods

let methodsCalledMetric =
   m.MethodsCalled.FillIterative(
       methods => methods.SelectMany(mm => mm.MethodsCalled))

let methodsCalled = methodsCalledMetric.DefinitionDomain

let responseLoc = methodsCalled.Sum(mm => mm.NbLinesOfCode)

select new { m, methodsCalled, responseLoc }
```

The result looks like:

[image: NDepend code query for response for a Method]

The set of methods called by any method can be either listed (by clicking the *136 methods* cell for example) or exported to the dependency graph to visualize it in a clearer way:

[image: call dependency graph produced by NDepend]